Twilio Verified Caller IDs did not send verification code
At first, I created a Twilio trial account using my phone number. I used the Twilio phone number as "from" and my number as "to." After finishing my code and sending a request to Twilio, I received the following response:
{
"name": "Error",
"message": "Failed to send OTP: Failed to send SMS: The number +84XXXXXXXXX is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify +84XXXXXXXXX at twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers",
"code": 500
}

Then, I went to the Verified Caller IDs section and saw that my number is verified. I wondered if something was wrong with my number, so I deleted it and added it again, but I didn't receive the verification code sent to my number. However, I can still use this number to log into Twilio. I have set up the Geo Permissions, but it hasn't affected the issue. Any ideas to solve this problem?
